# How can I sniff packets using Scapy without any CMD opened?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, scapy

I'm trying to write a script to sniff some packets and send others according to the sniff.

I also want that script to be completely invisible to the user (so it could only be seen from Task Manager).

I tried changing the script extension to `.pyw` so it would run with `pythonw.exe`, and it kind of works. However a PowerShell window opens up and when closed, shuts off the `pythonw` process as well.

I read some on the web and understood Scapy creates it in order to get access to low level networking requests. I also found code to change it into a regular CMD. However I don't want it to change to another shell type, I want this shell to disappear completely so there's no indication om the desktop that the script is running.

How do I achieve this? Is there a way to request scapy to create this shell as a background process? Or is there a way to move an already running CMD to the background?

Thanks in advance!

PS:
The code to change the PowerShell to CMD is:

```
POWERSHELL_PROCESS.close()
conf.prog.powershell = None
POWERSHELL_PROCESS.__init__()
```

After the import, and was found [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1387).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really understand what you are trying to do

This was a well-known bug in scapy, that opened in some IDE (e.g IDLE), the powershell would be visible. As shown in the link you provided, it has been fixed https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1387 so that the shell now is invisible.

If this is your issue, use the latest github version https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip

Comment: I tried it, and it isn't solved. I actually get an error for `from scapy.all import *` with the new version (for `pyw` or `py`, it doesn't matter).

Comment: What I try to do is to run `sniff` without any open window.

Comment: Could you share the error, your windows version and python version ?

Comment: Error: https://pastebin.com/nktN5zM3, Python version: `2.7.13`, Windows version `8.1`.